# Search for symbol in Oracle Solaris

Tags: c++11, solaris, solaris-studio

ALL,

First apologies if this belongs to Unix/Linux part of SO. But this question has a very thin line between those 2. If you feel I should post there let me know and I will move it. So here goes:

Im trying to compile a program on Oracle Solaris that can be successfully build on Linux with Solaris Studio.

However, I'm getting a lot of linker errors with the STL fuhnctions. My guess is that the Makefile generated is for Linux/gcc and it doesn't make into account anything else.

What is the way to search for a symbol in Solaris?

The command that was generated for Makefile is:

Igor Korot

Tue, Apr 16, 7:26 PM (15 hours ago)

to wx-dev
Hi,
I'm trying to see if wxWidgets 3.1.1 can be used on Oracle Solaris with
latest Solaris Studio 12.6.

The library compiled correctly however, when I try to build minimal I got this:

```
igor@solaris:~/wxWidgets/buildSol/samples/minimal$ make
CC -o minimal   minimal_minimal.o
-L/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib
-R/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib -mt  -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.1
-lwx_baseu-3.1        -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0
-latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0
-lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lSM -lgtk-3
-lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lnotify
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lXtst
-lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig
-lfreetype -lpng -lz -ljpeg -ltiff -llzma  -lwxregexu-3.1  -mt    -lz
-lsecret-1 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm -lz -lsecret-1
-lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm
```

And here are couple of errors it produced:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
std::wstring::_M_rep()const
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so
jpeg_CreateDecompress(jpeg_decompress_struct*, int, unsigned int)
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so
std::wstring::capacity()const
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so
jpeg_resync_to_restart(jpeg_decompress_struct*, int)
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so
std::streambuf::pbackfail(int)
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so
std::wstring::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t*,
std::wstring>, wchar_t)
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.so
std::wstring::basic_string()
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.so
std::wstring::basic_string() minimal_minimal.o
std::wstring::~basic_string()
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.so
std::wstring::~basic_string() minimal_minimal.o
std::wstring::operator=(wchar_t)
/export/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildSol/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a C++ standard library issue. There are different implementations of C++ out there. See if you can find another compiler/library that matches yours on Solaris.